# Regular Expression alert error

Tags: javascript

```
var regex =new RegExp('^\w{0,}\@[a-z]{0,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$');
var g = /^\w{0,}\@[a-z]{0,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
```

When I use .match with "regex", we get alert with null and when with "g" I get right alert. Say, I enter abc@co.in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In string you should use double `\\`:

```
var regex = new RegExp('^\\w{0,}\\@[a-z]{0,}\\.[a-z]{2,4}$');
```